# Error while uploading big files in Azure from c#, it throws "The specified block list is invalid."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I want to upload blobs in Azure container using c#. I am breaking the blobs into chunks in my UI (angular) and for each chunk I am calling my c# API.
This is working well for small files. But for large files (even of 130 MB) the file is not getting fully uploaded and the API throws the error "The specified block list is invalid."

```cs
[HttpPost("{fileName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadChunk(string fileName, List<IFormFile> chunk)
{
    if (chunk.Count == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file received from the request");
    }

    if (chunk.Count > 1)
    {
        return BadRequest("The request contains more than one file. Only one file can be uploaded at a time");
    }

    var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);
    if (!await blockBlobClient.ExistsAsync())
    {
        await blockBlobClient.UploadAsync(new MemoryStream());
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk[0].Length];
    await chunk[0].OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    var blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var blockIdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId);
    var base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(blockIdBytes);

    await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer));
    var blockList = await blockBlobClient.GetBlockListAsync(BlockListTypes.All);
    var totalBlockCount = blockList.Value.CommittedBlocks.Count() + blockList.Value.UncommittedBlocks.Count();  // This line just returned 14 blocks
    await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList.Value.UncommittedBlocks.Select(block => block. Name).ToList());
}
```

Comment: concurrent uploads with the same filename?

Comment: The same file I am breaking into chunks in the UI and sending to API for each of the chunks

Comment: But not the same file (or something different with the same filename) multiple times so that that a chunked upload conflicts on the Azure resource?

Comment: Do you mean I should kind of verify the blob ids before trying to commit them?

Comment: Can you share the names of the blocks returned here: `var blockList = await blockBlobClient.GetBlockListAsync(BlockListTypes.All);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have added the code below to the Program.cs and uploaded more than 130 MB file chunks to the Azure Blob Storage.***

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        });

        builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueLengthLimit = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        });
```

**Program.cs :**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        });

        builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueLengthLimit = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        });

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        var app = builder.Build();
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
```

**BlobController.cs :**

```cs
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlobController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;
    private readonly string containerName = "<container_name>";

    public BlobController()
    {
        var connectionString = "<connec_string>";
        blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    }

    [HttpPost("{fileName}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadChunk(string fileName, List<IFormFile> chunks)
    {
        try
        {
            if (chunks.Count == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No file received from the request");
            }

            if (chunks.Count > 1)
            {
                return BadRequest("The request contains more than one file can be uploaded at a time");
            }

            var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);

            if (!await blockBlobClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                await blockBlobClient.UploadAsync(new MemoryStream());
            }

            var chunk = chunks[0];
            var blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var blockIdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId);
            var base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(blockIdBytes);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk.Length];
            await chunk.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer));

            var blockList = await blockBlobClient.GetBlockListAsync(BlockListTypes.All);
            var uncommittedBlocks = blockList.Value.UncommittedBlocks.ToList();
            uncommittedBlocks.Sort((b1, b2) => string.CompareOrdinal(b1.Name, b2.Name));

            await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(uncommittedBlocks.Select(block => block.Name).ToList());

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

The process ran successfully as follows:

[image]

I uploaded file chunks to the Azure Blob Storage as shown below.

**Note:** Ensure you have a stable internet connection.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Azure Portal :**

I uploaded files of **130 MB** and larger to Azure Blob Storage as shown below.

[image]